# .NET MAUI Shell: How can `ShellContent` page be added to the navigation stack to enable "navigate back" behavior?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have several page in MAUI Shell XAML:

```xml
    <ShellContent
        Title="Dashboard"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage">
        <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf0db;" FontFamily="AwesomeSolid" Color="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource Gray100}}" />
        </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>

    <ShellContent
        Title="Ot"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:OtherPage}"
        Route="OtherPage">
        <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xe52f;" FontFamily="AwesomeSolid" Color="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource Gray100}}" />
        </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>
```

Shell navigation works fine, but if user taps "back" on `OtherPage` the application will not return the user back to the main page. Also, navigation from Shell Flyout does not add a back button to the `OtherPage`.

If I put a button on `OtherPage` and try to explore navigation stack it seems like it doesn't record previous page:

```cs
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count);  // prints 1

        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();  // doesn't work

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");    // doesn't work

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///MainPage"); // navigates to MainPage
    }
```

From the last call I can see that navigation is working, but navigating from Shell doesn't add page to the navigation stack.

How do I achieve the behavior that:

1. Application starts on `MainPage`
2. User navigates to `OtherPage` via Shell Flyout
3. User taps "back" button while on `OtherPage` and returns to `MainPage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell content in the Shell.Xaml will be default set as the root page in the navigation stack. In other words, when you navigates to a page via Shell Flyout, that page will be a rootpage.

And the back button will show only when you go to a page which is not added into the Shell as a flyoutitem. So both of the **OtherPage** and the **MainPage** will not show the back button when you navigation between the two pages. You navigate between the two pages with the `Shell.Current.GoToAsync` is same as using the Shell Flyout.

So you can remove one of the ShellContent and only use the `Shell.Current.GoToAsync` to navigate between the two page or only use the Shell Flyout.

**Update**

In the OtherPage's xaml.cs:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///MainPage");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the default behavior. But I need to get back button working when user navigates to `OtherPage` from the Flyout. Maybe there is some hook where I can store previous page and then handle the back button and perform navigation in my app code?

Comment: It seem you can only use `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///MainPage");` to get back to the MainPage. And you can also try to make the user return to MainPage in by override the `OtherPage's OnBackButtonPressed()` methos. You can check the update part in the answer. @Michael

Comment: By this way, the user will retrun to the MainPage when he click the physical back button.

Comment: got it, thank you! The issue is that in real app user can navigate between any pages listed in Flyout, so some mechanism needed to store the previous page.

Comment: But if the user navigates between the pages in the flyout, he can also get back with the flyout. And it seems there is no a such method to store the previous page when user navigate with the flyout. @Michael

Comment: Ok, got it! I just have several user requests that say that navigating back is more intuitive (I believe that it comes from web experience)

Comment: All right. Happy coding!